# File(AbsoultePath) telling me file not found

Tags: java, file, path

```
    private static String readPasswordFile(String masterPassFilePath) throws Exception
        {
            File masterPassFile = new File(masterPassFilePath);
            if (!masterPassFile.exists())
            {
                throw new Exception("["+masterPassFilePath+"] does not exist");
            }
}
```

with the masterPassFile being equal to:

```
C:\temp\master.pass
```

which the returns true for the if statement throwing the error.

I've tried a bunch of different `masterPassFilePath` values

```
C://temp//master.pass
C:/temp/master.pass
```

etc etc

other info the master.pass is a dat file

I'm kinda stumped

EDIT:

To respond about permission, yup I can access it I have created it.

The backslash forwardslash issue. No matter what I have tried

masterPassFile has always been equal to:

```
C:\temp\master.pass
```

now why would this return true for

`!.exists()`

Comment: Try `C:\\temp\\master.pass`. \\ is an escape character for \.

Comment: Does the file actually exist there?

Comment: file does exist there :) I have moved it about a few times to see if that was an issue

@Marnix Yeah sorry I've tried that too that was what was mean by etc etc. Also I'm passing them in as args within Eclipse so it takes care of the escape chars but I tried it to be doubly sure

Comment: using a '@' for the path string makes that windows automaticly uses the right '/', '\', or whatever. just use: @"C:\temp\master.pass" to be sure thats not the problem (if you're sure your file is there :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a modern Windows "**C:/temp/master.pass**" should work, if you have rights to the directory and file. With backslashes one needs to escape them in a java source: "**C:\\temp\\master.pass**". Try another file (maybe locked).

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting some kind of file permissions problem? Is this running in a context (tomcat for example) that may not have read access to the directory or the file. If this code is running in tomcat, is the security model turned on preventing access to files elsewhere?